# How can I winterize a set of Polaris heating units?

Tags: water-heater

We have 11 cabins that have Polaris water heaters with a copper tubing system that uses a blower to create the heat for the cabins.  We live in an extreme winter climate and sometimes the water heaters can be finicky. Currently we keep the heat on all winter and monitor the temps in the cabins.  However, we are going to be gone for a few weeks next winter with no one to monitor.  What is the best solution?  Is there a way to winterize the units.  I know some have told us to empty the water heater.  However with as finicky as they are we are wondering if this is safe?  Or will the components freeze and we have another problem? Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "finicky"?

Answer (score 0):

Draining the units is a good idea. Before you do that, you should pump RV Plumbing antifreeze into the system. That way any water remaining in the pipes will not freeze. Also do the toilet bowls and anything else that you think could hold water. The trick is to get it everywhere in the system. It's not always easy if you are not familiar with the principles of plumbing. There are heat exchangers and pumps in those Polaris units. Very expensive to replace due to freezing and cracking. Only do it if you are very confident that you can get the antifreeze everywhere. Don't simply drain the system as you may not get all the water out and risk destroying your units. Another option is WIFI thermostats that notify you if the heat shuts down. Very expensive for 11 cabins but a great solution for long term monitoring.